# How to assure that a button is only clicked a "n" times?! android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

this is a game, and this game have a certain number of rounds, i want to click that button only the number of rounds the player selected.

this is my function, that saves the last 2 words from a input string, and shows on a textfield, i just want to run this function the number of "introndas"... i tried adding that last part of the code with "next.setEnable(False)"... but did nothing...
Thanks guys

public  void onClick (View v){

```
    edText1=findViewById(R.id.txtatual);
    int introndas = Integer.parseInt(nrondas);
    String aux=guardatexto();
    String str[] = aux.split(" ");
    int lenghtofstr = str.length;

    if(lenghtofstr >=2){
    lword=str[lenghtofstr-1];
    pword=str[lenghtofstr-2];
    String wordstoshow=pword+" "+ lword;
    ltextview.setText(wordstoshow);

    FinalTexto=FinalTexto+" " + aux;}
    edText1.setText("");
    currentnumber++;

    if (currentnumber == introndas)
        next.setEnabled(false);
    else
        currentnumber = currentnumber + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an integer field in your `Activity` (or `Fragment`) that will store the number of that button pressed. Say `private int timesClicked = 0;`.

Then in `onClick()` check if this counter reached that limit you want. It could be

```
int timesClicked = 0;

public void onClick (View v){
  if(++timesClicked <= roundsSelected){
    // The limit is not reached yet...
  }else {
    // Player clicked button more times than the rounds selected.
    // Write logic here  
  }
}
```